# how to apply and show qty based discounts

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, grouped-products, promotions, tierprice

I'm pretty new to using Magento, I am running 1.9 CE. I have messed about with configurable products, bundled, simple and grouped - but in all honesty I think I'm going about this the wrong way.

Let me set the scene...

The store sells single sheets of A4 paper in various different colours. 
I have added the A4 sheets as simple products.

I'm looking for advice on how best to collate these products with various options and promotions, for example - I have then created  a grouped product named A4 and added all the different colour simple products as associated products linked to the grouped product.... this then gives the end user the ability to set the quantity for the different colours.  For example,

End user visits A4 Grouped Product and is presented with the different colours for each sheet. They can then select the QTY of each colour that they would like.

1x A4 Paper (any colour) cost £5.00
5x A4 Paper (any colour) cost £15.00

I have managed to create a Shopping Cart Rule which applies a discount  when applied to the cart however, I need the ability to show the price prior to being added to the cart.

I cannot seam to apply catalog price rules using QTY.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the custom options of a simple product? It's the very bottom tab in the magento admin page for adding a product. It gives the option for dropdowns or checkboxes etc, which will show customer pricing in whatever fashion you want?

Comment: Hi Blair. Using the simple products still doesn't give me the option to configure catalog promotion rules for different quantities? Thank you for the reply

Comment: In honesty, I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve. Question could be a little better worded. But I don't think there is a default setting of Magento or out of the box free extension that will do what you are looking to do.... Certainly if the tier pricing suggestion below doesn't work for you either in the price tab of a product page in Magento admin area.

Comment: Hi Blair, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Item1: (£5.00) 1x A4 Sheet  - will give the customer the option to select ONE colour from a dropdown. When the order is placed, the colour ordered will subtract by 1. For example, if the customer orders 1 Red sheet, the SKU: Ref will subtract by 1. Item2: (£15.00)
5x A4 Sheets – will give the option to select FIVE colours.

Comment: The stock needs to automatically adjust on the specific product to reflect what the customer has ordered. For example, if 3 red sheets and 2 black sheets are ordered, the SKU: Red will subtract by 3 and the SKU: White will subtract 2. The problem I am having is that both items relate to the same product. If I create a new attribute set within magento, I then end up with various products relating to the same colour.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the tier prive feature of magento

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-use-tier-pricing

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. Tier pricing applies per simple product. If I set tier pricing on SKU:- A4-White, then their would have to be 5 a4 sheets added before the promotion was applied. I need the ability to apply promotions to any of the a4 skus.

Comment: So if 5x a4-white the promotion is displayed on the cart. OR 2x a4-black / 2x a4-yellow / 1x a4-black